# Moving from HibernateTemplate to SessionFactory without @Transactional in tests

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, transactions, integration-testing

I'm working on moving to Hibernate 4 with Spring 3, which means I can no longer use Spring's HibernateTemplate. Refactoring the code was easy enough (replacing callbacks with sessionFactory.getCurrentSession() where a session is used) but I'm running into problems with my unit tests. In particular, I want to have completely live integration tests for my DAO -- no @Transactional usage.

However, because the HibernateTemplate is no longer providing the means to open a session if one isn't open, I get the "No session found for current thread." when I run my tests, because sessionFactory.getCurrentSession() does not open a session if one isn't open.

Is there any way to work around this to replicate what the HibernateTemplate was giving me without moving to using @Transactional in my tests? It seems like it should be possible but I can only get the tests to work when I annotate the test class with @Transactional (since that does open a session).

Comment: Is there a reason why you would not like to have a transaction started?

Comment: It adds overhead that, for these tests, is not necessary. I don't feel like the overhead is adding any value in this particular case, so that's why I want a work around.

Answer (score -2):

If you use Junit test it's very simple.

In your test class you have to load the Spring context:

```
@BeforeClass
public static void createApplicationContext(){      
    try {           
         applicationContext = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(
                new String[] {"applicationContext.xml"});           
         yourDao = (YourDao)applicationContext.getBean("YourDao");           
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Assert.assertNull(e);
    }
}
```

Then you can use `yourDao` and write the test logic.

Comment: What does this have to do with a Hibernate session?

Comment: I configure a Transaction Manager through Spring context:  
`<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">  
  <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"/>
  </bean>`. I use the annotation `@Tansaction` on the method of the DAO. Then loading my DAO in the test class in this mode works.